# Multiple buttons with the same xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to click on twitter reply button but the code is replying to the same tweet instead of replying to the next one

the xpaths of the comment buttons are the same, how can I tell to open the second

```
comment_button = '//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/section/div/div/div[2]/div/div/article/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]'
   
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(comment_button).click()
    sleep(1)
```

I have try this but no success

```
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(comment_button)[1].click()
    sleep(1)
    
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(comment_button)[2].click()
    
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(comment_button)[3].click()
```

Comment: This XPath works very specifically on just one element. You'd have to devise an XPath pointing to all of the comment buttons and iterate them with `find_elements_by_xpath()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: use a broader XPath that targets the comments buttons.

```
comment_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-testid="reply"]/div/div[1]')
# targets all "reply buttons" and only the first div in the tree (the other would target the number next to the comments)
comment_buttons[0].click()
sleep(1)
comment_buttons[1].click()
# and so forth
```

Note that the other comment buttons won't be clickable after you click the first one; you'd have to close it then you can move on to the next. The other tricky thing is Twitter uses infinite scrolling which means the number of elements in `comment_buttons` changes depending on how much you scroll down.

Comment: `UserWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead
  warnings.warn("find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\92\Desktop\new features test\new feature\Twitterbot.py", line 78, in <module>
    comment_buttons[0].click()
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize they've deprecated that command ... Try using just find_element_by_xpath and see if you're getting anything. I'm not sure how you're getting an empty list but it's not complaining that there's no matches by that XPath

Comment: It's working fine now thanks ! I want to know how can I call the next comment_button without adding [number]